# Calculate a value inside a group

Tags: pandas, group-by, pivot, geopandas

Suppose that I have a Pandas DataFrame name is df:

```
    Origin Dest T   R
0      N    N  100  3
1      N    A    2  6
2      A    B  356  7
3      A    B  789  8
4      B    N  999  9
5      B    A  345  2
6      N    A  456  3
```

I want to produce a DataFrame that for each group by Origin do the following calculation:

Sum values in column 'T' then divide with sum of the values in 'R' for each groups. I want to see this result in a origin_dest matrix form.

I am trying to following, but does not work.

```
Matrix_Origin =df.pivot_table(values=['T','R'], index='Origin', columns ='Dest', fill_value=0, aggfunc=[lambda x: df['T'].sum()/df['R'].sum() ])
```

This is what I want to produce:

```
Origin   N     A     B
N     33.33  50.88   0
A      0     0    76.33
B      111  172.5   0
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of groupby, with [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) can yield your desired outcome :

```
res = df.groupby(["Origin", "Dest"]).sum().unstack()


#divide column T with column R
outcome = (
    res["T"]
    .div(res["R"])
    .reindex(index=["N", "A", "B"], columns=["N", "A", "B"])
    .fillna(0)
     #optional
    .round(2)
)

outcome





  Dest      N     A      B
Origin          
   N    33.33   50.89   0.00
   A    0.00    0.00    76.33
   B    111.00  172.50  0.00
```

Comment: @ sammywemmy Thank you so much !